# How do I recreate the system.site configuration element?

Tags: configuration

For some reason `system.site`, `system.performance` and `system.date` config values have been deleted from our site.

I have the original configuration files, but when attempting to import those using drush cim, Drush complains about the site UUID mismatch.

```
The import failed due to the following reasons:                 
Site UUID in source storage does not match the target storage.
```

I assume this is because UUID is missing entirely. If I run `drush cget system.site`, I get the following error:

```
[error]  Config system.site does not exist
```

Attempting to set the UUID with `drush config-set "system.site" uuid "my site id"` also fails with:

```
[error]  Config system.site does not exist
```

So now I'm in a bit of conundrum.

Any suggestions on how to restore the `system.site` configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with Drush.

To get around the UUID mismatch I uncommented the UUID field in `system.site.yml` and ran `drush cim`. After that I specifically set the UUID by running `drush cset "system.site" uuid "my site id"`.